# GoogleDataTransport crashes and cant find file

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

Below I have listed the stack trace in Xcode. I have tried reinstalling the cocoa pods, updating the pods as well but no luck and have found little information on how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is any other information I need to provide.

```
2020-04-05 21:13:09.555949-0500 GameSwap[51550:2971887] [GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] There was an error reading extension bytes from disk: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “event-7173251720999561018” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/daltondomenighi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66EDB64D-A8FB-400F-84CC-56C088B9C565/data/Containers/Data/Application/C35B61D2-DCC5-466B-B1B0-403AA2D766AF/Library/Caches/google-sdks-events/event-7173251720999561018, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000019fa580 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

```
2020-04-05 21:13:09.556276-0500 GameSwap[51550:2971887] [GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] There was an error reading extension bytes from disk: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “event-7170068472913256371” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/daltondomenighi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66EDB64D-A8FB-400F-84CC-56C088B9C565/data/Containers/Data/Application/C35B61D2-DCC5-466B-B1B0-403AA2D766AF/Library/Caches/google-sdks-events/event-7170068472913256371, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001902730 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
tU7w8fz88VuWhXE3rtzt
```

```
2020-04-05 21:13:09.726324-0500 GameSwap[51550:2971890] [GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] (/Users/daltondomenighi/Desktop/GameSwap/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORStorage.m:152) : There was an error removing an event file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“event-7173251720999561018” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSFilePath=/Users/daltondomenighi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66EDB64D-A8FB-400F-84CC-56C088B9C565/data/Containers/Data/Application/C35B61D2-DCC5-466B-B1B0-403AA2D766AF/Library/Caches/google-sdks-events/event-7173251720999561018, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001937030 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

```
2020-04-05 21:13:09.726802-0500 GameSwap[51550:2971890] [GoogleDataTransport][I-GDTCOR001006] (/Users/daltondomenighi/Desktop/GameSwap/Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCORLibrary/GDTCORStorage.m:152) : There was an error removing an event file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "“event-7170068472913256371” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSFilePath=/Users/daltondomenighi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66EDB64D-A8FB-400F-84CC-56C088B9C565/data/Containers/Data/Application/C35B61D2-DCC5-466B-B1B0-403AA2D766AF/Library/Caches/google-sdks-events/event-7170068472913256371, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000019d9740 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```